# How to read text from Java server on Android Client

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets, printwriter

This is my first bit of code that isn't some fizzbuzz game or otherwise. I am trying to create a messaging application that runs on android, the current workflow is something like this:

Client sends message->Server stores text on local text file->Client receives and displays that text file in a TextView Element.

Currently I have the function as follows form the server end that sends the content in a printwriter using the file, no errors.

I also have on the client end a function that takes that incoming stream, and *purportedly* displays the stream on the textview

Respectively, here are the functions:

Server:

```
public void readContentFromFileWriteToSocket(Socket c){
        try{
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("content");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(c.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.write(fileIn.toString());

        }catch(IOException ignored){

        }
}
```

Client:

```
private class receiveSocketInput extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids){

        try {
                netConnect n = new netConnect();
                n.doInBackground();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(n.server.getInputStream()));
                String display = in.readLine();
                TextView board = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                board.setText(display);



        }catch(IOException ignored){
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The app does not display a text stream, or anything at all for that matter. It hangs right before the buffered reader and does nothing.

I realize my coding might be a little messy and I apologize in advance for that.

Comment: `n.doInBackground();` What is done there,?

Comment: @blackapps doInBackground is a function required if a class extends AsyncTask. that particular function is connecting to the socket I have established between server and client.

I dont believe the socket would be the issue, considering netConnect works on every other feature of the app.

Comment: You are not allowed to call doInBackground yourself. Execute your activity and doInBackground will be called automatically.

Comment: activity=asynctask